# If the derivative is nonzero on an interval, do the endpoints have to be the extrema?

Tags: calculus

Given a function $f(x)$ which is continuous and differentiable over interval $[a,b)$ such that $f'(x)\neq 0$ in that interval, do the minimum and maximum of $f$ lie at $a$ and $\lim_{x\to b}$? I remember seeing this somewhere, but I can't remember the name of the proof which is what I really need.

Comment: There may not be a maximum/minimum since the interval is open.

Comment: Is $f$ defined at $b$?

Comment: Yes, $f$ is defined at $b$. The interval is restricted as in the problem, but $f$ and $f'$ are defined for any $x\geq a$. @Zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, it is more precise to say that, if $f'(x)\neq 0$ in $[a,b)$, then $f$ can only have it's minimum and maximum at $a$ and $\lim_{b\rightarrow a}$

---

This looks like a corollary of Fermat theorem.

By contradiction, suppose there is $c\in (a,b)$ s.t. $f(c)$ is an extreme point of $f$ (w.l.o.g, assume $f(c)<f(x)$ for all $x\in[a,b)$). Then, for any $b'<b$ such that $c<b'$, we have $f$ is a continuous differentiable function at $[a,b']$, and $c$ minimizes $f$ over $[a,b']$. By Fermat's theorem, $f'(c)=0$, which contradicts the assumption $f'(x)\neq 0$ in $[a,b)$